# Keyless entry fails if aux power outlet in use

Tags: electrical, keyless-entry

I have a 2003 Pontiac Sunfire, if I have a device plugged into the aux power outlet in my car the keyless entry remote stops functioning. Won't unlock the car or open the trunk. Soon as I pull whatever device is connected it works fine.

I've replaced all of the fuses and it recently had it's engine replaced (though the issue occurred before and after engine replacement)

Should I replace the battery? What else can I do to the electrical system to make it work without issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What device is plugged in?  Can you try a different device?  It could be electrically noisy.

Comment: In addition to what is plugged in, is the cable straight or coiled?

Comment: It's a bluetooth radio adapter with USB ports (USB ports typically left empty), I'm picking up a car charger from Costco later today, will try with that and report back.